# Schengen Visa without H1 stamping

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, h1b-visas

I am on H1B status in the US. I have a valid I-797 form but not the H1 Stamp.

I am planning to go to India next month to get my stamping. But as I wanted to travel Europe before going to India, I applied for Schengen Visa, and I got it.

My question is

1. Will I have a problem when boarding the flight in the US (to Netherlands) as I don't have a valid H1 stamp?
2. Will there be an issue after landing in the Netherlands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the Schengen visa, so you have little to worry about.  Some people have trouble because some Schengen consulates want to see a certain period of validity in your US status evidenced by a valid visa, making the situation uncertain for people in your situation.  But you have cleared that hurdle.

To get into the Schengen area, you will need a visa, which you have, and a credible plan to visit and leave the Schengen area that should be fairly close to the one you presented in your visa application.  In other words, as long as you don't change your plans too much, you shouldn't have any problems.

A US airline may ask to see your visa when you leave (European airlines do not do this on departure, in my experience), but since it's not required to have a valid visa to leave the US, they should allow you to leave even if you show them an expired US visa or no US visa at all. They will be far more interested in your Schengen visa.

After you land in the Netherlands, nobody will care about your US visa until you get to the US consulate in India, where you will get a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I've traveled to Europe and then to India as planned. I did not have any issues at the port of Entry in Europe.

Comment: As @saketh modugu in an answer: did you go to the Netherlands consulate for the shengen visa?

Comment: @sid - which consulate did you apply for the Schengen visa in the US?