# Can I get a Schengen visa with an expired US visa?

Tags: usa, schengen, schengen-visas, visa-expiration

I am an Indian citizen on an H1B visa in US. I am planning to visit India but on the way would like spend 1 week in Europe.

Situation: I have an extension (I797 and I94) to stay in the US, but my visa stamp on the passport is expired. The plan is to visit Europe from the US, stay for a week and then go to India and renew my US visa and come back to the US.

With the above situation, can I apply for a Schengen visa from the US with an expired US visa?

Comment: Why do you think an American visa has any relevance to an Indian national obtaining a Schengen visa? You final destination is your home country.

Comment: @WeatherVane many countries require at least some proof that you are legally in the country you are applying from, or in some cases that you are actually resident there (with the paperwork to prove it). I’m not quite sure this is consistent among Schengen countries but I’m too lazy to check the Schengen visa code at this time.

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143388/schengen-visa-without-h1-stamping

Answer (score 4):

- You can apply *from* the US since this is your current place of residence.
- If your plans are to stop in Europe on the way to India, there will be no question that you *can* leave the Schengen area since you are an Indian citizen on the way to India.
- However, there may be questions if you *want* to leave the Schengen area. Having a valid US work permit and a well-paid job would help. Not having them does hurt your application.